# How to get just Query Plan for Query that is timing out?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have a Data Explorer query(*) that is timing out.  My sql badges are telling me that I could tune it if I had the Query Plan, but since the query never finishes the "Include Query Plan" check box isn't helping.  Is there some way to *only* get the query plan (i.e., not actually try to run the query), as we could in Management Studio?

(* - someone else's, I am trying to use it as a starting point for my intended query since I am unfamiliar with Data Explorer's schema)

Comment: Database schema: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so as soon as I posted this my sql badges started yelling at me "*No, you idiot.  You're supposed to be the SQL expert, YOU should be able to figure this out and answer it yourself.*"

Oh, right.

So I tried adding SET SHOWPLAN_XML to the query test and checked "Include execution plan" and it worked.  Like this:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;
go

<SQL query that times-out>
;
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;
GO
```